# Slick Future Returning Empty

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am running a slick query and successfully getting a result with this helper method:

```
  def exec[T](action: DBIO[T]): T = Await.result(db.run(action), 2.seconds)
```

I am trying to implement non-blocking futures, [per the Slick docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/dbio.html#materialized):

```
  def execFuture[T](program: DBIO[T]) = db.run(program)

  val futureTest = execFuture ( maxInStockVal.result ).onComplete {
    case Success(x) => x
    case Failure(e) => e
  }
  Logger.debug(futureTest.toString)
```

The result I'm getting is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the result, you should put the print inside the `onComplete`, like the docs says:

```
f.onSuccess { case s => println(s"Result: $s") }
```

Outside that function you do not have access to the result, since the code inside runs latter asynchronously, you should wok with `maps`, `reduces` and other things to work with the results, and always work with [Futures](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html).